# SQL select max values

Tags: sql

I have for example values 'X','Y','Z',' ' in column myValue

and want to do something like select max(myValue)

so I want one value, the one with the highest value where X=1, Y=2 and Z=0

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: What is the one with the highest value?  I don't understand what you are looking for.

Comment: Could you please see my post and let me know, if that is what you want. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select max(
    case myValue
        when 'X' then 1
        when 'Y' then 2
        when 'Z' then 0
    end) myValue
from myTable
```

Comment: Yeah this worked, I added to it and did it like this ,decode((max(decode(eight,'IPV',50,'SCH',40,'RSLV',30,'VER',20,'',10,100))), 50,'IPV',40,'SCH',30,'RSLV', 20, 'VER', max(eight)) eight

Comment: Happy to help! If you find this response useful, please consider marking it as the answer to your question. Thank you! :)

Answer (score -1):

```
(select max(PurDate) as mb,prodid as pd
from batch group by ProdId ) as rs 
on p.RndId = b.ProdId 
and p.ComId = c.RndId
where b.PurDate = rs.mb 
and b.ProdId = rs.pd 
and p.RndId in (select distinct prodid 
                from TranItem as ci, TranMain 
                as tm 
                where tm.RndId = ci.TranId 
                and tm.Invdate between '2016-May-01' and '2016-May-31')
```

Comment: please put your code in a code block using control + K.  Also provide a little explanation for your solution.